Pop up to slider
I have this situation where the iterations (history) of an order are shown in a popup with multi select option for comparison, comparison table is a vertically long table. When I click compare –

Is it better to show the comparison table in the popup itself by replacing the history? Note: pop up height will change to a higher value to hold  the comparison table with scroll, which will create a sudden height change in popup or should I need to set a min-height to the popup by default (which will create empty space if there is only 3 iteration).
OR
Is it better to show the comparison on a slider? Will this popup to slider create a bad user experience?

Please let me know the best option for this situation.

Does '… history of an order' mean a purchase order? What kind of product is it?
What is the width of the comparison table? Can it fit as a sidebar? Or are talking about a wide and long-scroll table?

History in this case is iterations of the same order ID - like a pdf which goes through a review to identify mistakes. after identifying issues, a revised pdf is re-uploaded (second iteration) ..like that there could be n number of iterations before the pdf is clear of all mistakes.

I cannot picture your UI in my head. What is a "comparsion on a slider" and "popup to slider"? Can you make a scribble to explain the layout and your two ideas? Generally: If you have a button to initiaie the comparison, it is okay to popup a new window. The user is anticipating something "to happen".
